# Home Current Meter - is this a good solution?

Tags: arduino, wireless, wifi, current-measurement, power-meter

I want to build a simple current meter to measure my power usage at home, and have the data sent to my blog's database. (I know there are similar solutions out there, but this project seems engaging for me to try on my own.)

Is the following specific workflow a viable solution?

1. A current clamp clips around the incoming mains power + in the breaker box.
2. A small processor nearby receives input from the clamps and determines power usage. (this will be by the breaker, any idea how to get power to it easily? And I'm thinking about using an arduino unless there's a better solution, thoughts?)
3. This small computer communicates over the home's wifi and sends my blog's database information at regular intervals.

Is there an easier/more effective way to send my blog power usage data from the whole house?

Comment: Just curious, what part of getting power to a power distribution panel would be difficult? Can't you just add an outlet to your ring main next to your panel?


Also you won't really need two current clamps, since one will be measuring the current into the house and the other back out they will be the same, unless you wanted to check for earth leakage or something but I'm not sure how feasible that would be.

Comment: @DanNixon I don't know much about utility electricity, just small stuff. I'm sure it's easy, but what is the best way to create an outlet right near a breaker box? And that's a good point about the clamp, I probably do only need one.

Comment: You should check this open source energy monitor out: [Open Energy Monitor](http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/)

Comment: @Brad I just found that and I think I will follow it. Is there a simple way of adding an outlet near a breaker box? Or some other way to plug it in?

Comment: If your house is typical US wiring you will need two clamps to measure both phases.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for the tip, I've heard both ways (you need 1, or you need 2). I am in the US, why do you need clamps on both phases? IE can you not just multiply the current in one phase by 2? Or do some outlets draw from one phase only, while others draw from both?

Comment: @Jeff Good point there, I'm in the UK so am used to almost all domestic supplies being single phase. I'm not sure on the standards for domestic wiring in the US but in the UK we have a set of parallel wired outlets with both ends connected to the breaker (hence the term ring main), so I would just disconnect one end and add another outlet and reconnect it to the breaker.

Comment: I realise my description was awful, so here is a diagram that shows a few ways to add a new outlet, due to the location adding a new outlet which is part of the ring would be easiest: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ring_circuit.svg

Comment: @JoshF Most US circuit breaker boxes are made so that half of the 110 breakers are on one phase and the rest are on the other phase. So you could measure one a double it, but you would be subject to large errors.

Comment: Measuring current is not measuring chargable-power by a significant margin.

Comment: In the UK, you may have to notify the local authority and get an extra socket inspected by a competent person  (at least, in Scotland, if you're in a flat or a house with three or more storeys; I'm not sure of requirements elsewhere in the UK). Check your local laws before adding an extra socket.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the data (as opposed to doing a project), then other people already have a solution for you:

https://www.flukso.net/

The software is open source and the hardware is available from their shop (current clamp/wifi enabled metering device).

Comment: thanks for sharing that. Not quite what I was looking for since I want to DIY, but I'll vote it up since it's still useful. Oops, since I'm new on the EE site, it won't let me vote yet. Well, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a great approach.

I did a very similar project using the Arduino Yun.

The Yun is a good choice because it works well with Wi-Fi (e.g. PuTTy terminal on your phone)  and the cloud (e.g. Google Drive).

I wrote up exactly how to do it on Instructables. Take a look at [Yun based Electricity Monitor with Cloud Support / Temboo and Google Drive](http://www.instructables.com/id/Yun-based-Electricity-Monitor-with-Cloud-Support-T/).

Answer (score 0):

I found a few ways to build a current meter one of which was [this cool guide](http://www.w8ji.com/building_a_current_meter.htm).

Maybe check [this](http://electronicdesign.com/test-amp-measurement/easy-build-ac-power-meter) out too.

Our of all of these I think that [this Arduino guide](http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/58) is one of my favorites because its pretty simple and well written.

Maybe you could put these together and it will meet your needs.
Happy hacking :)

P.S: Welcome to electronics stack exchange! Just for the future, the guidelines stipulate you should usually try to google around before asking a question. But cool question, thanks for asking.